# Do not change updated_at attribute if a certain attribute is being changed

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have an `Article` model in Mongoose, with several attributes, one of which is a boolean, `approved`.

I also have two date attributes, `created_at` and `updated_at`. I'm handling these two using the following function:

```
ArticleSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    'use strict';
    var now = new Date();
    this.updated_at = now;
    if (!this.created_at) {
        this.created_at = now;
    }
    next();
});
```

Using this code, `updated_at` is being changed even if I only approve the article - however, I'm using the `updated_at` attribute to show a tiny "Edited" text, if `updated_at !== created_at`.

Is there a way I could get `updated_at` changed if any of the attributes BUT `approved` is being changed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Document#modifiedPaths()` method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-modifiedPaths) to list all modified paths:

```
ArticleSchema.method('isUpdated', function () {
    'use strict';
    var modified = this.modifiedPaths();
    switch (modified.length) {
        case 0:
            return false;
        case 1:
            return !~modified.indexOf('approved');
        default:
            return true;
    }
});

ArticleSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    'use strict';
    var now = new Date();
    if (!this.created_at) {
        this.created_at = this.updated_at = now;
    } else if (this.isUpdated()) {
        this.updated_at = now;
    }
    next();
});
```